# Why the value of Enum didn't change when I set in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I am try to set the Enum value to a variable , but the value of variable didn't change when I get it back.

The code is like the following:

**CouchbaseEnum.swift** save the enum value.

```
class CouchbaseEnum{
    enum ReplyStatus{
        case NONE
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS
        case LOGIN_ERROR
        case LOGIN_RETRY
    }
}
```

**Couchbase.swift** define the function for `set` and `get` the value.

```
class Couchbase {

    var STATUS = CouchbaseEnum.ReplyStatus.NONE;

    func setReplyStatus(status: CouchbaseEnum.ReplyStatus){
        STATUS = status;
    }

    func getReplyStatus() -> (CouchbaseEnum.ReplyStatus){

        return STATUS;
    }
}
```

**ViewControler.swift** call the function and set the enum value to variable.

```
@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {

    Couchbase().setReplyStatus(CouchbaseEnum.ReplyStatus.LOGIN_SUCCESS);

    if(Couchbase().getReplyStatus() == CouchbaseEnum.ReplyStatus.LOGIN_SUCCESS){
        println("login---LOGIN_SUCCESS");
    }else if(Couchbase().getReplyStatus() == CouchbaseEnum.ReplyStatus.NONE){
        println("login---NONE");
    }
}
```

When I click the button , it will call `setReplyStatus` and send `CouchbaseEnum.ReplyStatus.LOGIN_SUCCESS`.

But it always show `login---NONE` , why the value didn't change when I call `Couchbase().setReplyStatus(CouchbaseEnum.ReplyStatus.LOGIN_SUCCESS);` in `ViewController.swift` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STATUS` is an instance variable of the class `Couchbase`.
Every time you call `Couchbase()`, you are creating a new instance of the class `Couchbase` and each time a new instance is created the `STATUS` gets set to `CouchbaseEnum.ReplyStatus.NONE`. Instead use a variable  like the code below.

```
var cbase = Couchbase()
cbase.setReplyStatus(CouchbaseEnum.ReplyStatus.LOGIN_SUCCESS);

if(cbase.getReplyStatus() == CouchbaseEnum.ReplyStatus.LOGIN_SUCCESS){
    println("login---LOGIN_SUCCESS");
}
else if(Couchbase().getReplyStatus() == CouchbaseEnum.ReplyStatus.NONE){
    println("login---NONE");
}
```